# Flutter & Firebase Messaging custom sound and heads-up message

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wanted to add ability to receive push notifications with custom notification sound in my app. To do so, I decided to create custom Notifications Channel with flutter_local_notifications plugin and placed this code in my main.dart file:

```
AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'classy_notifications', // id
    'Main Classy Notifications Channel', // title
    'Channel for Classy homeworks notifications.', // description
    importance: Importance.max,
    enableLights: true,
    playSound: true,
    sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('classy_not'),
  );
```

And that function in `initState()` of my main.dart file:

```
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
```

Thats is my notification sound placed in `raw` directory:

[image]

For my test Firebase Function, I placed this in my payload variable:

```
const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: "Classy",
            body: "Body test",
            android_channel_id: "classy_notifications",
            channel_id: "classy_notifications",
            sound: "classy_not",
            priority:"high"
        }
    };
```

Notification's title or body is displayed normally on my phone - only sound and priority aren't working. IS there a way to fix it?